# Package only imports when I run python3

Tags: python, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I just installed a package and the first step to testing (found [here](http://www.clawpack.org/dev/first_run_fortran.html)) tells me to cd into a "tests" directory and run nosetests. Nosetests gives me a ModuleNotFoundError:

```
ERROR: Failure: ModuleNotFoundError (No module named 'clawpack')
```

which is prompted when each of the tests import clawpack (the package).

#### What I have figured out so far:

If I run "python" in my home directory, I can use the command "import clawpack" without error. However, when I am in the tests directory, "import clawpack" only works if I run "python3" and not "python." If I am running "python," "import clawpack" gives me the same ModuleNotFoundError above.

Any suggestions for how to rectify this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: When in your `tests` directory, do `python --version` on the command line. What does it say? Is it different from `python3 --version`? How about when you're in your home directory? This seems like a path / version issue in that your computer isn't running the correct version of python under certain circumstances.

Comment: seems like you have different versions of python installed. Uninstall the old one and keep only python3 so it'll be chosen as default always

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thank you for the quick reply. Python --version gives 3.7.1 and python3 --versions gives 3.9.4 in the tests directory and in the home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have multiple Python versions installed, and packages installed with one version won't be available to the other. You can test which Python version you are using with `which python` and `which python3`.

How are you installing `clawpack` with `pip`? To ensure you are using the `pip` utility that corresponds to the correct Python binary, you can run `python3 -m pip install clawpack`.

Also, if you have a folder for `clawpack` in your home directory, then the folder in your current directory is what is imported.

Comment: This is what I get from which python:

(base) Users-MacBook-Pro-2:~ User$ which python
/Users/User/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) Users-MacBook-Pro-2:~ User$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3

Another comment suggests that I delete one of these versions. Is this dangerous?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to delete one of the versions, but having a single primary Python environment makes things simpler. It looks like the `python` binary points to your Anaconda install and `python3` refers to the one installed under /Library. Also, (base) refers to your virtual environment, which is how Anaconda isolates Python packages, which may be why you can't import `clawpack`.